# SQL: How to find a record with 2 associations with separate WHERE clauses?

Tags: sql

Tables:

```
users
id: int // users has_many chat_users

chats
id: int // chats has_many chat_users

chat_users
id: int
chat_id: int (foreign key) // chat_users belongs_to chat
user_id: int (foreign key) // chat_users belongs_to user
```

The database has these records:

```
users, id: 1
users, id: 2
users, id: 3

chats, id: 1 // <---------
chats, id: 2

chat_users, id: 1, chat_id: 1, user_id: 1 // <-------
chat_users, id: 2, chat_id: 1, user_id: 2 // <-------
chat_users, id: 3, chat_id: 2, user_id: 2
chat_users, id: 4, chat_id: 2, user_id: 3
```

Given I have 2 user_ids `1` and `2`, how would I write a query to the chats table to find a chat with:

1) a chat_user with user_id == `1`

AND

2) a chat_user with user_id == `2`

?

Comment: Please, next time provide sample data as DDL+DML and add the relevant rdbms tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select all the chat_ids with one of the users, then select all the chats that also have the second user:

```
SELECT * from chat_users where 
user_id = 1 AND chat_id in (
    SELECT chat_id from chat_users where user_id = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a chat only occurs between two users, then we can simply aggregate the `chat_users` table by `id` and check that the minimum `user_id` is one and the maximum `user_id` is two.

```
SELECT id
FROM chat_users
GROUP BY id
HAVING MIN(user_id) = 1 AND MAX(user_id) = 2
```

Comment: As you said, if there are only 2 users in the chat, then this is a very good answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

In your `WHERE` statement use `IN`:

SELECT *
FROM chat_users
WHERE user_id IN (1, 2)

I don't see why you would have to write it on the `chats` table when you have the data `chat_id` in the `chat_users` table. Unless there's more data you are looking to pull from the `chats` table, in which case you would `JOIN` the `chats` table.

Comment: This won't work, but instead would return any chats having user `1` _or_ user `2`.

Comment: True. After looking at the other answers, I realized he probably wasn't asking to not have all chats from either of those 2 users.

Answer (score 0):

If you need other details from the chat, I'm assuming those would be kept in the `chats` table. To get to that, use

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id AS chatID,  <other chats.cols>
FROM chats c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT c1.chat_id 
    FROM chat_users c1 
    INNER JOIN chat_users c2 ON c1.chat_id = c2.chat_id
        AND c2.user_id = 2
    WHERE c1.user_id = 1
) c3 ON c.id = c3.chat_id
```